# Don't have permissions to create folders or delete files in $HOME

Tags: shell, permissions, sudo

I have lost the permissions to create files/folders in `/home/user` without using `sudo`. I have a few snippets below of what I mean.

I tried to install [nyxt-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nyxt-git) from the AUR beforehand and it errored out. Then I shut my computer down for the night and now when I booted it up this morning I get the below errors.

How might I change my permissions back? I'm not entirely sure if it's related to my attempt at installing the package but it was the last thing I did before having this issue.

```
⋊> ~ pwd                                                                                                                                                                                                  
/home/user
⋊> ~ touch test.py                                                                                                                                                                                         
touch: cannot touch 'test.py': Permission denied
⋊> ~ rm Untitled.ipynb                                                                                                                                                                                     11:28:37
rm: cannot remove 'Untitled.ipynb': Permission denied
⋊> ~ mkdir testing                                                                                                                                                                                         
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘testing’: Permission denied
```

My OS is EndeavorOS and I am running AwesomeWM.

The output of `ls -ld "$HOME"` is,

`dr-xr-xr-x 54 hank hank 4096 May 14 11:35 /home/hank/`

Comment: Please add `ls -ld "$HOME"` to your question, and identify your username if it's not shown

Comment: what are the permissions on your home directory? show the output of `ls -l /home`

Comment: @roaima Sorry for the late response, I haven't been at my computer the past couple days. I updated the post with the output for `ls -ld "$HOME"`.

Comment: @imabug I updated the post. The output is `dr-xr-xr-x 54 hank hank 4096 May 14 11:35 /home/hank/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your home directory permissions:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 54 hank hank 4096 May 14 11:35 /home/hank/
```

are missing the write permission for the owner of the directory (you).  The fix ought to be very simple:

```
chmod u+w /home/hank
```

You might have to invoke that chmod command under sudo, but try it as yourself first.

Comment: Definitely not under `sudo`

Comment: The directory is owned by the user, so `sudo` wouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:*** *Since this answer was submitted, sufficient information (`ls -ld "$HOME"`) to answer the question has been added to the original question. Please refer to the accepted answer.*

You'll need a bit more useful debugging information.

- the user you are; `whoami`
- the groups you belong to; `groups $(whoami)`
- the owner and groups of the directory/files you're trying to modify; `ls -l ~/`

Depending on what this tells you, you may or may not be able to use `chown` on your home directory (and it's children files/directories) to restore the permissions. There's a good chance that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88356/changing-ownership-of-home-folders) will work for you, but I can't say with the information provided.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should include my username or not so I left it out. The username is `hank` and this is the output of the `groups` command `sys wheel rfkill hank`. The permissions of the folders from the third command are `drwxr-xr-x`.

Comment: The permissions (rxw flags) are important, they are clustered flags for "read/write/executable" for the "user" "group" and "other". The following pieces of information are also important, i.e. "which user?" and "which group". It should probably say something like `drwxr-xr-x hank wheel`. If the `rxw` flags are off, you'll be able to fix that with `chmod`, and if the `hank group` aren't right, you can fix those with `chown` (the referenced answer).

You may also want to check `ls -l ~/..` to see the permissions of the actual home directory, not just it's contents.

Comment: I tried the referenced answer and it didn't fix the issue. Though here is a few lines of the output for the `ls` coimmand. Everything has permissions `drwxr-xr-x  3 hank hank      4096 Jan  1 17:27 Music/`
`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      4096 May 15 11:32 nyxt/`. Everything has a number then `hank hank` after the permissions except for the `nyxt` folder which is `root root`.